# Change the color of specific letter in console

Tags: matlab

I am forming an specific string using several `strcat` and displaying it into console. This string contains characters such as: `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`,`0`,`#`,`*`,`E` and am using `fprintf('%s')` for this purpose.

For instance:

> 2E4137E65922#

is a possible outcome of the code.

Is there anyway I could make letter `E` to stand out in my output? Like making it red?

Comment: How is `2E4137E65922#` stored?

Comment: @IKavanagh As I said, it's a string as a result of several `strcat`

Comment: No you didn't. "it's a string as a result of several strcat" is not contained anywhere in your question. Can you isolate the `E` before a `strcat()` operation?

Comment: @IKavanagh any of those 13 letters would be concatenated in a `if`..`else if` structure in the code. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Dev -iL for this information!

While it seems that `cprinf()` from my other answer does not work for single characters, if there is a single color that one wants to use, and that color is orange, then this trick used for `warning` in `cprintf` can be used:

```
disp(['this is [' 8 'orange]' 8 ' text'])
```

Read more at: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/another-command-window-text-color-hack

Thus, your code would look like:

```
s='2E4137E65922#';
C=strsplit(s,'E');
str=C{1};
for ii=2:size(C,2)
    str=[str ['[' 8 'E]' 8 ]];
    str=[str C{ii}];
end
disp(str);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunatedly, there is no official way of doing this. However, you could use Yari Altman's [`cprintf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24093-cprintf-display-formatted-colored-text-in-the-command-window). It abuses of undocumented features of Matlab to do exactly what you want.

You  can read more in the famous [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cprintf-display-formatted-color-text-in-command-window) blog he runs.

The example image in FEX looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT:** Theoretically, if `cprintf` would work as expected, the following should work:

```
C=strsplit(s,'E');
cprintf('black',C{1});
for ii=2:size(C,2)
    cprintf('err','E');
    cprintf('black',C{ii});
end
cprintf('black','\n');
```

However, in Matlab 2014b it doesnt give good results. I found out that of it doesnt work properly when there is a single character to format.

If you substitute 'E' by 'EE' works....

**EDIT2:** I left a comment to Yari Altman. Hopefully he will, if he can, fix the thing.

Comment: Tnx Ander but the problem of devising a smart algorithm to differentiate `E`s in the string and apply `cprintf` to them is still missing. Right?

Comment: @Bababarghi you are rigth. `strsplit` should help, but I am having troubles making `cprintf` work properly. It seems that formating a single character doesnt work very nicely, at least in 2014b.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the HTML tags `<strong>`, `</strong>` to type specific letters in bold:

```
str = '2E4137E65922#'; %// input string
letter = 'E'; %// letter that should be made bold
strBold = regexprep(str, letter, ['<strong>' letter '</strong>']); %// output string
disp(str)
disp(strBold)
```

Comment: Is there any chance I could get `strBold = regexprep(str, letter, ['<FONT color="red">' letter '</FONT>']);` to work instead?

Comment: I also tried it, but `disp` doesn't seem to recognise that tag