# How can one print colored messages from mex files

Tags: matlab, mex

while developing mex files, often I have error handling inside. For that, I have a function `checkErrors`, that trows errors to MATLAB basically by doing:

```
mexPrintf("%s \n",msg);\
mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("Mymexfile:Thisspecificfucntion:",errorString);
```

However, this will print in black whatever is written in `mexPrintf` but will not show the Error and MsgID , just a red colored "error in Mymexfile".

Is there a ways for either: show the errorID and errorTxt in red, or make `mexPrintf` show the text in red in the MATLAB command window?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to change the color of strings that you print on the screen.

Comment: @RandomGuy there are definitely ways of changing the color if called from MATLAB directly  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694074/change-the-color-of-specific-letter-in-console

Comment: @AnderBiguri Taking a look into `cprintf` function on MATLAB Central, one may see that printing formatted string in the Command Window required manipulating the underlying Java `com.mathworks.mde.cmdwin.CmdWinDocument` object and exploiting the ability of interpreting HTML.. Now, whether `mexPrintf` is the thing to use or not... that's a good question. Anyways, here's the code: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24093-cprintf-display-formatted-colored-text-in-the-command-window/content/cprintf.m